# How to add/initialize members in an SML state or state machine?

Tags: c++, c++17, boost-sml

I designed this state machine using [boost::sml](https://github.com/boost-ext/sml)

```cpp
struct LooperStateMachine {
    auto operator()() const {
        using namespace sml;
        
        return make_transition_table(
                *"beggining"_s + event<heel> / onRecordFirstLoop.value() = "recording_first_loop"_s,
                "recording_first_loop"_s + event<heel>[is_heel_valid] / onRecordLoops.value() = "recording_other_loops_and_playing"_s,
                "recording_first_loop"_s + event<toe>[is_toe_valid] / onPlayLoops.value() = "playing_loops"_s,
                "playing_loops"_s + event<toe>[is_toe_valid]/onStopPlayingLoops.value() = "stopped"_s,
                "playing_loops"_s + event<heel>[is_heel_valid]/onRecordLoops.value() = "recording_other_loops_and_playing"_s,
                "recording_other_loops_and_playing"_s + event<toe>[is_toe_valid] / onPlayLoops.value() = "playing_loops"_s,
                "stopped"_s + event<toe>[is_toe_valid] / onClearLoops.value() = "beggining"_s,
                "stopped"_s + event<heel>[is_heel_valid] / onSaveLoops.value() = "stopped"_s
        );
        
    }

    std::optional<std::function<void()>> onClearLoops;
    std::optional<std::function<void()>> onSaveLoops;
    std::optional<std::function<void()>> onPlayLoops;
    std::optional<std::function<void()>> onRecordLoops;
    std::optional<std::function<void()>> onRecordFirstLoop;
    std::optional<std::function<void()>> onStopPlayingLoops;
};
```

However, to use it, the `sm` auto instantiates it:

```cpp
int main() {
    using namespace sml;

    sm<LooperStateMachine> sm;
```

So I don't get a chance to set my functions.

How can I set the functions?

Comment: "*auto instantiates it*" How does `auto` apply to this "instantiation"? That just looks like regular old default initialization. Why aren't you providing a default constructor if you want the type to be initialized in some special way? What is that special way, and how would overloading the function call operator accomplish this?

Comment: @NicolBolas you mean passing arguments like this: `sm<LooperStateMachine> sm(5)`? I added a constructor that takes an `int` but I get `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/boost-experimental/sml/master/include/boost/sml.hpp:381:5: error: static_assert failed due to requirement 'missing_ctor_parameter<LooperStateMachine>::value' "State Machine is missing a constructor parameter! Check out the `missing_ctor_parameter` error to see the missing type."
    static_assert(missing_ctor_parameter<TMissing>::value,
    ^ `

Comment: @NicolBolas I need to pass things from outside the struct

Comment: @NicolBolas https://github.com/boost-ext/sml/blob/938027d76a6f0c50992dbb486642c31c3d76fd11/include/boost/sml.hpp#L1713 there is no way to pass arguments I think

Comment: Flipping through some docs real quick tells me they will probably want you to inject these from the ctor arguments. But as they say, it will become unweildy quick, so consider dependency injection: https://boost-ext.github.io/sml/tutorial.html#5-create-a-state-machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To your *literal* question you might just provide a default constructor/NSMI. However I get that you want to be able to "dynamically" switch out these action "hooks".

About injecting the function hooks, the docs [say](https://boost-ext.github.io/sml/tutorial.html#1-create-events-and-states:%7E:text=SML%20states%20cannot%20have%20data%20as%20data%20is%20injected%20directly%20into%20guards%2Factions%20instead):

> SML states cannot have data as data is injected directly into guards/actions instead

This gave me the idea to separate your **runtime** state from the state machine:

> Aside: optional functions are redundant, `function<>` can already be value-less and has a convenient conversion to bool fdr that, just like `optional<>`.

**[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YMP3xH15ekMrtpam)**

```
#include <boost/sml.hpp>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
namespace sml = boost::sml;

namespace looping {
    struct heel { };
    struct toe { };
    static auto is_heel_valid = []() { return false; };
    static auto is_toe_valid = []() { return false; };

    using DynamicAction = std::function<void()>;
    struct Hooks {
        DynamicAction onClearLoops;
        DynamicAction onSaveLoops;
        DynamicAction onPlayLoops;
        DynamicAction onRecordLoops;
        DynamicAction onRecordFirstLoop;
        DynamicAction onStopPlayingLoops;
    };

    static auto onClearLoops       = [](Hooks &hooks) { if (hooks.onClearLoops)       hooks.onClearLoops();       };
    static auto onSaveLoops        = [](Hooks &hooks) { if (hooks.onSaveLoops)        hooks.onSaveLoops();        };
    static auto onPlayLoops        = [](Hooks &hooks) { if (hooks.onPlayLoops)        hooks.onPlayLoops();        };
    static auto onRecordLoops      = [](Hooks &hooks) { if (hooks.onRecordLoops)      hooks.onRecordLoops();      };
    static auto onRecordFirstLoop  = [](Hooks &hooks) { if (hooks.onRecordFirstLoop)  hooks.onRecordFirstLoop();  };
    static auto onStopPlayingLoops = [](Hooks &hooks) { if (hooks.onStopPlayingLoops) hooks.onStopPlayingLoops(); };

    struct LooperStateMachine {
        auto operator()() const {
            using namespace sml;
            
            return make_transition_table(
                *"beginning"_s + event<heel> / onRecordFirstLoop = "recording_first_loop"_s,
                "recording_first_loop"_s + event<heel>[is_heel_valid] / onRecordLoops = "recording_other_loops_and_playing"_s,
                "recording_first_loop"_s + event<toe>[is_toe_valid] / onPlayLoops = "playing_loops"_s,
                "playing_loops"_s + event<toe>[is_toe_valid]/onStopPlayingLoops = "stopped"_s,
                "playing_loops"_s + event<heel>[is_heel_valid]/onRecordLoops = "recording_other_loops_and_playing"_s,
                "recording_other_loops_and_playing"_s + event<toe>[is_toe_valid] / onPlayLoops = "playing_loops"_s,
                "stopped"_s + event<toe>[is_toe_valid] / onClearLoops = "beginning"_s,
                "stopped"_s + event<heel>[is_heel_valid] / onSaveLoops = "stopped"_s
            );
        }
    };
}

int main() {
    looping::Hooks hooks;
    hooks.onClearLoops = [] { std::cout << "Clearing them\n"; };

    sml::sm<looping::LooperStateMachine> sm(hooks);
}
```

Disclaimer: I have only the flimsiest understanding of this library. I find it to be a mind bender to get to grips with, but in an increasingly positive way.