# Calling Substate machine constructor using boost-ext::sml

Tags: c++, boost, boost-sml

I was wondering if its possible to initialize a substate machine by using a non-default constructor.
I know one can do:

```
sub = sml::state<Sub>;
```

And use the `sub` I.e:

```
auto sub = sml::state<Sub>;
return make_transition_table(
     *"init"_s + event<Start>   / print(data_) = sub
     ,state<Sub> + event<End>  / print(data_) = X
 );
```

But if the `Sub` statemachine has a non-default constructor, is it possible to use that constructor to initiate the machine and then use that in the `Composite` machine?

Example:

```
struct Sub
{
    Sub(int){}
    auto operator()() const {
        using namespace sml;
        return make_transition_table(
            *"Entry"_s + event<ES1> = X
        );
    }

};
```

Here is an example:
https://cpp.godbolt.org/z/zjvWsvscY

Complete example code:

```
namespace sml = boost::sml;

struct Context
{
    int x_{};
};

struct Data
{
    int y_{};
};


struct Start{};
struct End{};
struct ES1{};

auto print(Data data)
{
    return [data](Context& ctx) 
    {
        std::cout << "Context: " << ctx.x_ << " data: "<< data.y_ << '\n';
        ++ctx.x_;
    };
}

struct Sub
{
    //Sub(int){}
    auto operator()() const {
        using namespace sml;
        return make_transition_table(
            *"Entry"_s + event<ES1> = X
        );
    }

};



struct Composite
{
    Composite(Data data): data_{std::move(data)}{}
    auto operator()() const {
        using namespace sml;
        auto sub = sml::state<Sub>;
        return make_transition_table(
            *"init"_s + event<Start> / print(data_) = sub
            ,state<Sub> + event<End>  / print(data_) = X
        );
    }

    Data data_;
};


int main()
{
    //Sub sub{};

    Data data;
    Context ctx;
    sml::sm<Composite> sm(Composite{data}, ctx);
    sm.process_event(Start{});
    sm.process_event(ES1{});
    sm.process_event(End{});
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not convinced this is possible (unless you use the Boost DI integration, maybe?). See also my earlier encounter https://stackoverflow.com/a/66217733/85371

Comment: Thanks!
I'm starting to lean against that its not possible, and that sending a context through injection is the only way to get data to a substate. The link further reinforces my understanding that this is probably not possible.  I guess one way to do it is to build Context that mirrors the statemachines hierarchi i.e

`
struct Context {
   Composite {
       ....<Data>....
        struct Sub_1 {
            ...<Data Sub1>...
          };
 };
`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can initialize `Sub` at the same time you initialize `Composite`, you might be able to handle it the same exact way that you're already doing.

Here is an example: https://cpp.godbolt.org/z/YKxWzcPza

Add `Sub{someint}` to the `sm` constructor:

```
sml::sm<Composite> sm(Composite{data}, Sub{666}, ctx);
```

Corresponding sub state and action:

```
auto printSub(int z)
{
    return [z](Context& ctx) 
    {
        std::cout << "Context: " << ctx.x_ << " z: "<< z << '\n';
        ++ctx.x_;
    };
}

struct Sub
{
    Sub(int z): z_{z}{}
    auto operator()() const {
        using namespace sml;
        return make_transition_table(
            *"Entry"_s + event<ES1> / printSub(z_) = X
        );
    }
    int z_;
};
```